# How to create a static (non-refreshing) menu bar like Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface

I'm wondering how to make (in rails) a menu (or header) bar that does not load on various page requests like how facebook does. Can you please brief on what kind of technologies Facebook uses for this and how can I replicate that mechanism in rails3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[PJAX](https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails)** loads html from your server into the current page without a full page load. It's ajax with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button that fully degrades.

Comment: Now I face a situation where I need to load page specific JS and CSS files by page specific I mean according the controller that is being accessed. But I couldn't get PJAX to load JS or CSS files. Is there a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

the technique is called ajax, you have to make all the links work as ajax requests and update only the needed part of the page...

you can have your layout split in two

```
<div id='header'>
  your code here...
</div>
<div id='content'>
  yield
</div>
```

now you can use the :remote => true option on the link_to tag on rails so the request will be an ajax request

then you have to serve an .js view to change the content of the div with id "content" with the code for your view

your .js should do something like... (suppose you are using jQuery)

```
$('#content').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => your_file.html.erb)) =>');
```

that's the basic idea, you have to play with ajax

I guess facebook also uses HTML5's pushstate to change the location address https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history so you can use the back/forward buttons of the browser