# Facebook URL AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a static (non-refreshing) menu bar like Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106786/how-to-create-a-static-non-refreshing-menu-bar-like-facebook)

How Facebook ajax work technologies? Can you tell me how change URL without refreshing page and static header in rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106786/how-to-create-a-static-non-refreshing-menu-bar-like-facebook/11107906#11107906)

**[PJAX](https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails)** loads html from your server into the current page without a full page load. It's ajax with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button that fully degrades.

Answer (score 1):

Use history.pushState() to change the browser URL without reloading the page.
http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

You can then add an event listener to the popstate event and react accordingly when the back button is used.